# Is it possible to dynamically instantiate custom polymer element passing JSON data

Tags: json, dart, polymer, dart-polymer

Is it possible to pass complex data like a JSON array to a custom element instantiated dynamically?

I want to instantiate an element passing him a big JSON array.
This element will, for each row of the JSON array, initiate sub element, passing them the JSON row.
I want to know how to pass JSON data to a dinamically instantiated element

Like:

1. `<my-list>` element will populate itself by first retrieving JSON data then dynamically creates sub elements with the freshly acquired data
2. For each row it will programmatically (from dart file) create a `<my-list-item myData="">` passing the given JSON array row to the `<my-list-item>` element as `myData`

Is it possible? If yes, how to pass the data when you create your sub element?

My current equivalent of my-list.dart:

```
@PolymerRegister('my-list')
class my-list extends PolymerElement {
  @property int listSize;        // number of blink tickets per panel

  MyList.created() : super.created() {
    //retrietve
    JSON data = //will find later how to use JSON
    //Init
    initializeList(data);
  }

  void initializeList(JSON data) {
    for row in data {
      BlinkTicket ticket = new BlinkTicket(row);
    }

  }
}
```

My list-item.dart:

```
@PolymerRegister('my-list-item')
class MyListItem extends PolymerElement {

  @property JSON data;

  factory MyListItem() => new Element.tag('my-list-item');

  MyListItem.created() : super.created() {
    //init self with data
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<dom-module id="my-list-item>
...
</dom-module>

@PolymerRegister('my-list-item')
class MyListItem extends PolymerElement {
  factory MyListItem() => new Element.tag('my-list-item');
  MyListItem.created() : super.created();

  @property Map data;
}
```

and then instantiate it from the future parent element like

```
List json = JSON.decode(getSomeJson());
for(var item in json) {
  var some = new SomeElement();
  Polymer.dom(root).append(some);
  // or to add it to the light DOM instead of the shady/shadow DOM
  // Polymer.dom(this).append(some);
  some.set('data', item);
}
```

(not tested)